# How install iceweasel in CentOS

Tags: installation, centos, iceweasel

I am looking for a way to install iceweasel in my CentOS.Before posting here I have googled but didnt find the solution any place.

Please help me to install iceweasel in my CentOS.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not firefox? Its the same thing.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes but it takes low RAM and I like it pretty much.

Comment: I suppose it still supports java when firefox don't